# Can't combine the two xpath expression in a single one

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I've written an xpath to locate a certain element. However, the thing is the element i'm after may be available in either childNodes[10] or childNodes[12]. I'would like to create an expression combining the two in a single expression and it will still locate the both irrespective of its position. The two expressions are:

First one:

```
 element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='data']/table//th")
 name = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].childNodes[10].textContent", element).strip()
```

Second one:

```
 element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='data']/table//th")
 name = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].childNodes[12].textContent", element).strip()
```

I tried like this but won't get any result:

```
 element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='data']/table//th")
 name = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].childNodes[10].textContent|return arguments[0].childNodes[12].textContent", element).strip()
```

How can I cement the both in a single expression? Btw, I'm using this xpath in python + selenium script.

Here is the link to the html:
"https://www.dropbox.com/s/vl8anp8te48ktl2/For%20SO.txt?dl=0"

Comment: could you share the html? and do you want to grab the text or any other attribute?

Comment: Thanks Gaurang Shah for your answer. It is only text I'm trying to grab.

Comment: is it working? if not could you put a html snippet of the code

Comment: What do you get in case you're scraping 10-th child, but need 12-th? Do you get an empty string?

Comment: Yes sir. In that case I get an empty string. I tried with try block, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of text nodes is an empty string you can try:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='data']/table//th")
name = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].childNodes[10].textContent", element).strip() or driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].childNodes[12].textContent", element).strip()
```

This should return you `name` with non-empty string (the first occurence of non-empty text node)

Comment: You are just impossible sir Andersson. It did the trick. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

how about this, 
following will give you an input element at index 10 or 12

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='data']/table//th//*[position()=10 or position()=12]/input")
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working. I'm gonna attach the html file.

Comment: Hi Gaurang Shah, see above. I've attached a link to the html.

Comment: are these two different `td` with same class or you just make it seprate?

Comment: No. I just pasted as i found.

Comment: but in this case `th` doesn't have any child element

Comment: May be you are right but with the above pasted two different xpaths I can grab them.

Comment: it's because javascript works bit different to get elements, `childnodes` gives you `br` and all the `text` as element. Webdriver don't. so for webdriver `th` is just an element. everything inside that is text.

Comment: how about this `text = "".join([element.text for element driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='data']/table//th")])`

Comment: Thanks again Gaurang Shah for your answer. However, i need only the second text but your one will give all the text.